# MongoDB Nested - Search TrackingValues

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

We need to perform a phrased-based search (like Google's "") over a nested array of key words, by order.

For instance, let us suppose the data looks like:

```
{
   Name: "question",
   body: [
    "We",
    "need",
    "to",
    "perform",
    "a",
    "search",
    "like",
    "google's"
  ]
}
```

By searching: "we search" – I will get no result, but the document will be returned by searching any of the followings: "we need", "to perform a search", "we" etc.

I do need to tokenize the words for encryption, so saving them as a string could not do for me here…

Is that any possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks, I tried to solve it with the technical support of MongoDB. Apparently, there is not out-of-the-box solution.

I have been able to "solve" this by keeping another field, concatenating all the tokenized, encrypted words in one string, and use regex expression over it.

Not ideal, and required to duplicate some data – but it works foe our needs.